# JavaScript: Post with Dictonary in body, never returns any values (curl pr PHP example works)

Tags: javascript, curl

I am trying to get a simple user by ID. In my case the field is called userID and the ID is 150. I know from the server, that this user exists. I also get returned all users, so the connection is fine.

This is what I tried:

```
 var dict = new Object();
    var dict = {
      "userID": "150"
    };
    

    
    fetch(url, 
      {method:'POST', 
       headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username+ ":" + password), },
         body: JSON.stringify(dict),       
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

But no matter, I will always receive a payload of 0.

From the official docs of the server it says:

"You need to send a params dictionary in the POST body. This is a key, value pair array of your method’s input parameters. If you’re unsure of what these are, they can be seen when you run a method in Kumulos’ control panel".

They even post an example:

```
curl -X POST
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     -H "Accept: application/json"
     -H "Authorization: Basic base64EncodedUsername:Password"
     -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
     -d 'params[photos]=1
         &params[timeCreated]=1462060800'
    "https://api.kumulos.com/b2.2/yourAPIKey/getNewPhotographers.json"
```

Saying they gave as parameters "timeCreated".

Even in PHP, they claim this would work:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "params[photos]=1&params[timeCreated]=1462060800",
```

is my "translation" to javascript that wrong?

Only from what the docs say, would you agree that my code is correct, or is the issue with me?
I also havent been able to get the correct results from postman with these parameters.

Thank you !

EDIT:

I was however able to get the correct data doing it the old way:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(username+ ":" + password));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};
   var data = `params[userID]=150`;

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: I see you don't set `Content-Type` in your JS code, but you do in your `curl` call -- could that make a difference?

Comment: You're sending URL-encoded parameters in `curl`, not JSON.

Comment: Why do you initialize `dict` with `new Object()` and then overwrite it on the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example shows that the API expects URL-encoded parameters, not JSON. And the parameter names need to be enclosed in `params[...]`.

The equivalent JS is

```
let body = Object.entries(dict).map(([key, value]) => 
    encodeURIComponent(`params[${key}]`) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)).join('&');
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(username+ ":" + password), 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: body
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, I cannot get your code to work. There seems to be a few syntax errors. (no ' at autohratizen and content-type) Can you see my edit however, I got it to work "the old way"...

Comment: Just needed to quote `Content-type`

Comment: Yes, itrs true. But it still returns no results. I notice that in "the old way" the data part is called `params[userID]=150` which works. How does that translate?

Comment: I assume that was just an example, and in your case you needed to send different parameters.

Comment: I am still a bit confuesed. I got it to work giving the body the following string: 
body: `params[userID]=150` I still dont know how that translate to the modern jason...

Comment: I've updated the answer to use that format.

Comment: Fantastatic. That works. I would have NEVER come up with this myself.